# VSTS IP Address Ranges

Tags: firewall, ip, deployment, visual-studio

I have an application on VSTS/visualstudio.com

I would like to set up continuous deployment to AWS.

I currently restrict access to the database server with whitelisted IP on the firewall.

This means visual studio can't access the database server.

Is it possible to get the IP address range used by visual studio online so I can add it to this list?

Thanks

Comment: Nor quite clear why the question was closed. VSTS is not "unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments"

Comment: Tell me about it

Comment: Still unresolved

Comment: I'd be interested too to hear proper way to identify IP range.